# Oracle date comparisons

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Say I have the following code

Some Sql query... is followed by this condition

```
AND EndDate < TO_DATE('02/14/2011','MM/DD/YY')+1
```

Is it that same as

```
AND EndDate <= TO_DATE('02/14/2011','MM/DD/YY')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note: I am assuming based on your to_date formatting that the EndDate is a date field and not a date/time data type.

Both queries should return the same result set.  Consider the following:

```
--Substitue "EndDate" for SYSDATE for this exercise

-- Does "EndDate" occur before June 01, 2011? (Yes)
SELECT 'TRUE'
FROM DUAL
WHERE  TRUNC(SYSDATE) < TO_DATE('05/31/2011','MM/DD/YY')+1

-- Does "EndDate" occur on or before May 31, 2011? (Yes)
SELECT 'TRUE'
FROM DUAL
WHERE  TRUNC(SYSDATE) <= TO_DATE('05/31/2011','MM/DD/YY')
```

Both results would yield "TRUE".  What doubts are you having?

Comment: When I try the first one I am getting 2766 rows or something when I try the second one I am getting 2300 rows or something. If it equals to the same condition then shouldn't it return me the same set of rows.

Comment: Are you qualifying on anything else?  What happens when you wrap TRUNC() around endDate in  your query?  How many rows are returned?

Comment: CJ - When I use Trunc it is returning me the same number of rows. So now I understand both are true.

Comment: Good deal.  Feel free to mark as answered if you feel that is the case.

Answer (score 2):

Depends if EndDate is a DateTime or just a Date.  If EndDate = 2/14/2011 3:00:00, the second one would be false but the first true.

Comment: If the field is just a date the code you gave will work just fine.